# I18n in Rails module

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

I would like to use I18n in a Rails utility module which is in my lib directory.  The utility method gets invoked in a mailer.

The module is defined like

```
module MyUtils
  def self.build_collection_full_email(collection)
    I18n.t('app_name') + " <" + self.build_collection_email(collection) + ">"
  end
end
```

The mailer has a call like this:

```
sender_name = MyUtils.build_collection_full_email(@collection)
```

However, when this gets run in the context of the mailer, I get an error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `I18n' for Rails:Module
```

It seems like I need to include a dependency so that the utility method knows how find the I18n module, but I haven't been able to find this in the documentation for I18n.

Answer (score 0):

do require 'i18n'  in this file